# Why this aws python lambda test sample bothers with deleting mocked resources in tearDown

Tags: python, unit-testing, aws-lambda, mocking

[The sample I refer to is here](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-test-samples/blob/69d3a3759272c180ccdd62e67e2245539107c52e/python-test-samples/lambda-mock/tests/unit/src/test_sample_lambda.py#L188C11-L188C11)

When the resources are mocked (in test setup), it seems that removing them afterwards is not needed.

Or is it advisable for some reason anyway?

```
    def tearDown(self) -> None:

        # [13] Remove (mocked!) S3 Objects and Bucket
        s3_resource = resource("s3",region_name="us-east-1")
        s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket( self.test_s3_bucket_name )
        for key in s3_bucket.objects.all():
            key.delete()
        s3_bucket.delete()

        # [14] Remove (mocked!) DynamoDB Table
        dynamodb_resource = client("dynamodb", region_name="us-east-1")
        dynamodb_resource.delete_table(TableName = self.test_ddb_table_name )
```